# code convert unique chars to '?' in postgreSQL queries

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have an automation code that runs a bunch of queries into Postgresql DB.

one of my queries is :

```
CREATE TABLE 行 (CustomerName int, City varchar(255),Country varchar(255))
```

when running it into the DB, I got this response:

```
Query response from db: 
CREATE TABLE ? (CustomerName int, City varchar(255),Country varchar(255));
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "?"
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE ? (CustomerName int, City varchar(255),Country ...
                     ^
postgres=#
```

it seems that it converts the unique char to '?'.

any suggestion why this could happen?

I'm sure that before the query is executed the letters are encoded correctly.

(when running this query manually everything goes well)

Comment: why do you created table with name using chinese words? @Orly Orly

Comment: for testing :) @Dolphin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would avoid using keyword characters, or international characters.

If you really need to do that you can try to use `"` double quote

> Quoted identifiers can contain any character, except the character with code zero. (To include a double quote, write two double-quotes.) This allows constructing table or column names that would otherwise not be possible, such as ones containing spaces or ampersands. The length limitation still applies.

[SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)

```
CREATE TABLE "行" (CustomerName int, City varchar(255),Country varchar(255))
```